# Help with Griffiths & Harris, Surfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, books, curves-and-surfaces

I believe to have found a typo in Griffiths & Harris.

In the chapter on surfaces, section Rational Surfaces 1, I am trying to read the result that a holomorphic vector bundle over $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ is a sum of invertible bundles.

What is the exact sequence that shows up at the start of his argument?  Mine only has 2 terms and involves the fibres of E and H, which doesn't really make sense to me.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Consider the "term" in that exact sequence that makes no sense because it's two terms written next to each other. Now put an arrow between them. Presto---you're back on track!

Comment: Hi Robert,

There are many many typos in Griffiths and Harris. I've only gone through Chapters 0 and 1, but marked up my book in many places. I can show you next term when you're in my Kahler manifolds class.

Comment: For the proof in the algebraic case, and a clever remark, try section 10.5, page 129, of Algebraic varieties, by George Kempf.

Comment: (I have removed some gendered language.  I hope I have not changed any intended meanings.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $H$ be the divisor corresponding to the point $x\in \mathbb{P}^1$. Tensoring the exact sequence 
$$
0\to O_{\mathbb{P}^1}(-H)\to O_{\mathbb{P}^1}\to O_x\to 0.
$$ with $E\otimes H^k$, gives
$$
0\to O_{\mathbb{P}^1}(E\otimes H^{k-1})\to O_{\mathbb{P}^1}(E\otimes H^{k})\to E_x\otimes H_x^{k}\to 0.
$$Here GH writes $E_x\otimes H_x^{k}$ for $E\otimes H^k\otimes O_x$, or what is the same, the fiber of $E\otimes O(H^{k})$ over $x$.

Comment: What exactly is the final sheaf that appears there?  I don't understand.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have my copy of Griffiths and Harris in front of me, but regarding Grothendieck's theorem, there's a nice elementary argument by Michiel Hazewinkel & Clyde F. Martin.  Here is a link to [ScienceDirect](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6V0K-45F627B-11&_user=10&_coverDate=08%252F31%252F1982&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_origin=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1522265683&_rerunOrigin=google&_acct=C000050221&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=10&md5=0e9c05feae6ce06554528c56b65cd8e8&searchtype=a).  It's only five pages, and mostly consists of linear algebra (and really, is closer to 3 pages, ignoring abstract, intro, and white space at the end).

Comment: The classical theorem is called the Kronecker Pencil Lemma. There is a proof in one of Gantmacher's books on matrices. I also recall a modern proof in the book "Vector Bundles on Complex Projective Spaces", by Okonek et al.

Comment: The link to `sciencedirect.com` is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1016/0022-4049(82)90037-8](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(82)90037-8) ([Zbl 0489.14005](https://zbmath.org/0489.14005)).